# TFS rest api Invoke-restmethod "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive"

Tags: powershell, tls1.2, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to invoke TFS and/or Azure DevOps REST Api in one of the powershell tasks in release pipeline in Azure DevOps. I tried running the same rest api code in two different servers (w/ azure pipeline agent installed) but one of them is working and one of them returns "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive..". The two agent servers have both tls 1.1 and 1.2 enabled. the working server has powershell v 4.0 and the server that returns error has v5.0.

When I ran "[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol," both servers returned ssl3, Tls.

I have a workaround for the server that returns error by using 
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
but I would like to know why I need to force using TLS 1.2 on one of the servers and not the others when they seem have same TLS configuration.

[image]

Comment: For the one that works, there’s probably a system wide setting that enables tls 1.2 in .NET

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing much else of the server, a registry key setting might be set on that server with PowerShell V4.

You can check the following reg keys to see if they have the following properties:

```
'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NetFramework\v4.0.30319' -Name 'SchUseStrongCrypto' -Value '1' -Type DWord


'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NetFramework\v4.0.30319' -Name 'SchUseStrongCrypto' -Value '1' -Type DWord
```