# Get-CrmConnection failing when executed from non-admin context (3.3.0.857)

Tags: powershell, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics

I'm trying to execute `Get-CrmConnection` to connect to Dynamics 365 from Powershell, but the command returns the following when executed from a non-administrative Powershell context:

```bsh
Get-CrmConnection -ConnectionString "AuthType=Office365;Username=xxx;Password=xxx;Url=https://xxx.crm.dynamics.com"

Get-CrmConnection : Failed to connect to CRM: Unable to Login to Dynamics CRM
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-CrmConnection -ConnectionString "AuthType=Office365;Username=crm_ ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (:) [Get-CrmConnection], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : -10,Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.CrmConnector.Powershell.Commands.GetCrmConnectionCommand
```

I have version 3.3.0.857 of the connector installed.

**Additional Info**

If I execute the same command within the context of an Administrator prompt, I'm able to connect without issue.

I need this command to work outside of an Administrator context because this script will be called as part of an Azure DevOps pipeline. When executing this code within the pipeline, hosted in Azure DevOps, the same issue occurs.

Comment: This command needs to touch the backend core COM objects. So admin privileges are required for it. But I will follow if there is any other recommendation. I am sure you will not encounter this issue if you run this in elevation mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to find a solution to my issue that doesn't involve elevating to Admin.

Using the `-Verbose` option when running `Get-CrmConnection`, I saw that the error that was occurring was that the connection was being forcibly closed by the host. After a little Googling, I ran across [this](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/microsoft-dynamics-crm-forum/265106/get-crmconnection-problem-powershell-script---installation-microsoft-portals-in-crm-9) forum post. The last post had a suggestion to try adding this to my script:

```bsh
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
```

I tried that and now everything works, admin or not.

Comment: Glad it worked out! Also, PowerShell by default doesn't have TLS1.2 enabled, so you'll need to set the security protocol object every new terminal session. There's also a registry key you can set on your machine to enforce this. You can reference my other SO answer here for that. Hope this helps! :)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57048820/tfs-rest-api-invoke-restmethod-the-underlying-connection-was-closed-an-unexpec/57062255#57062255

Answer (score 0):

You can run any script in elevated mode with the following:

```
$script = "-file C:\crmscript.ps1"
Start-Process powershell -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList $script
```

You can get valid verbs for any process using the `System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo` object under the verbs property. Which, in this case, `RunAs` is a valid verb to start the powershell process in elevated mode.

You can then incorporate this into your Azure Pipelines/DevOps.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware that I could do that!